# Calculate the bounds of the visible part of the map

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a map and an element placed over it. The map is on the **entire screen**(100% for both height and width).

How can I calculate the bounds of the **VISIBLE** map(without the part covered by the element)?

I attached a picture below. The blue element is over the map, and I want to get the bounds within the red rectangle.

[image]

Comment: If you want to calculate the size of the red rectangle, you can get the height of the map with `document.element.clientHeight` and subtract the blue element's height.

Answer (score 2):

The map bounds can give you one corner, we just have to calculate another one. Let's go after the Northeast one (top right):

1. take the [pixel origin](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#map-getpixelorigin) (top left) of your map:

   ```
   var pxOrg = map.getPixelOrigin();
   ```
2. add the dimensions of the blue rectangle:

   ```
    // let's say it's your blue rectangle
    var $cover = document.getElementById('cover');

    var deltaX = $cover.offsetLeft + $cover.getBoundingClientRect().width;
    var deltaY = $cover.offsetTop + $cover.getBoundingClientRect().height;

    // pixel coordinates of the NE corner
    var pxNE = pxOrg.add(L.point(deltaX, deltaY));
   ```
3. [reproject to coordinates](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#map-unproject), you now have your Northeast corner

   ```
    var ne = map.unproject(pxNE);
   ```
4. get the map bounds, grab the Southwest corner, and build the final result

   ```
   var bounds = L.latLngBounds(map.getBounds().getSouthWest(), ne);
   ```

And a demo

```js
var map = L.map(document.getElementById('map')).setView([48.8583736, 2.2922926], 15);

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);


var pxOrg = map.getPixelOrigin();

var $cover = document.getElementById('cover');
var deltaX = $cover.offsetLeft + $cover.getBoundingClientRect().width;
var deltaY = $cover.offsetTop + $cover.getBoundingClientRect().height;
var pxNE = pxOrg.add(L.point(deltaX, deltaY));

var ne = map.unproject(pxNE);

L.marker(ne).addTo(map);

var bounds = L.latLngBounds(map.getBounds().getSouthWest(), ne);
console.log(bounds.toBBoxString());
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
#container {
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index:1;
}
#cover {
  z-index:2;
  width: 100%; height: 100px; background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.2);
  position: absolute; left:0; top:0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    
<div id='container'>
  <div id='map'></div>
  <div id='cover'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `L.Map.containerPointToLatLng`. Let me quote [the documentation](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#map-containerpointtolatlng)...

> Given a pixel coordinate relative to the map container, returns the corresponding geographical coordinate (for the current zoom level).

So you can fetch the southeast (bottom right) `LatLng` by calling `map.getBounds.getSouthEast()`, and then the northwest `LatLng` by doing something like...

```
// Get the height of the overlapping element
var h = document.getElementById('cover').getBoundingClientRect().height;

// Pixel coordinates of the desired northwest corner, relative to the map
// container
var px = [0, h];

// And convert to LatLng
var neLatLng = map.containerPointToLatLng(px);
```

Once you have the NE and SW corners, it should be trivial to construct an instance of [`LatLngBounds`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#latlngbounds).